# Getting rid of pressed effect in JavaFx toggle Button

Tags: javafx

How can I get rid of the pressed effect of javafx toggle button? Essentially, I want the look and feel of the button to be the same except the background image.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS file, you can do

```css
.toggle-button:armed {
    -fx-color: -fx-base ;
}
```

You might also want to remove the hover effect:

```css
.toggle-button:armed, .toggle-button:hover {
    -fx-color: -fx-base ;
}
```